# Removing Duplicate rows from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I would like to know how you would remove duplicate rows from a IEnumerable. I have this code:

```
public IEnumerable <Shipments> Shipments
        {
            get
            {
                Debug.Print("Initiated");
                
                foreach (var item in Loads)
                {
                    if (item.ShipTo.Contains(" "))
                    {
                        
                        foreach (var item2 in Routes.Where(d => d.DockCode == item.ShipTo.Substring(0, item.ShipTo.IndexOf(" ")) && d.CarrierDeparture.TimeOfDay == item.ShipTime.TimeOfDay))
                        {
                                yield return new Shipments() { Arrival = item2.CarrierArrival, Departure = item2.CarrierDeparture, Issuer = item.Customer, Destination = item.ShipTo, LoadType = item.LoadType };
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

which gives me this data using it as a item source

[image]

My goal is to only return new shipment if one that is the same doesn't exist. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Does/can your Shipments type implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode`?

Comment: What is "the same shipment"?

Comment: @GuruStron example 2 is the same shipment as 1

Comment: @SmackYouIn2.3 it does not answer my question =) Should all fields be equal? Or there is some other logic?

Comment: "not all ship to have spaces but I still need to parse those ones as well." But the `if` makes it so *only* records with a space get returned. I don't understand the "as well" part of your statement.

Comment: @itsme86 yeah lets not worry about that one for now. That would be a separate question.

Comment: You could create a new collection using linq groupby https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @GuruStron The logic is it is comparing two collections and adding into new shipments using the foreach statement the thing is it is duplicating. I hope this is what you are asking for :D

Comment: Then you should explain what your definition of "duplicate" is in this scenario. Is it any records with the same `DockCode`? Do all of the fields need to match?

Comment: @itsme86 duplicate will be same `DockCode` && same  `Carrier Arrival`

Comment: @SmackYouIn2.3 obviously not. The last comment does though.

Comment: what about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-3.1 ? Distinct() with your custom Comparer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a class that implements `IEqualityComparer<Routes>`:

```
class RoutesComparer : IEqualityComparer<Routes>
{
    // Might want to add null checks here.
    public bool Equals(Routes route1, Routes route2) =>
        route1.DockCode == route2.DockCode
        && route1.CarrierArrival == route2.CarrierArrival;

    public int GetHashCode(Routes obj) =>
        obj.DockCode.GetHashCode() ^ (obj.CarrierArrival.GetHashCode() * 13);
}
```

Then pass that to `.Distinct()`.

```
foreach (var item2 in Routes.Where(d => d.DockCode == item.ShipTo.Substring(0, item.ShipTo.IndexOf(" "))
    && d.CarrierDeparture.TimeOfDay == item.ShipTime.TimeOfDay).Distinct(new RoutesComparer()))
```

Comment: IEnumerable doesn't contain a definition for Distinct

Comment: It does. [See](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/t70tmv this is what I am getting on the foreach after implementing your suggestion.

Comment: @SmackYouIn2.3 I didn't realize the type was `Routes` instead of `Shipments`. I've updated my answer to use `Routes` instead.

Comment: is it suppose to be `route1.dockcode == route2.dockcode`?

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but I am getting this when loadin the data into the datagrid: https://prnt.sc/t71026

Comment: @SmackYouIn2.3 One more answer update. I forgot about `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: I apologize i've never heard of gethashcode unless it's GTA modding lol. That worked. I accepted. Thank you for your help!

Comment: actually it's better, but there still is duplicates: https://prnt.sc/t715a6

Comment: This datagrid is the `IEnumerable<Shipments>`

Comment: were you able to help me get the duplicates removed?